# Mongo function to validate data imported from JSON file

Tags: json, mongodb, mongoose, mongoimport

Is there any way to validate data that I imported from json file using `mongoimport` or other third-party tools like [Studio3T](https://studio3t.com/)

If I have `example.json` file like that:

```
[
  {  
    "firstnumber" : 3, 
    "secondnumber" : 2, 
  }
]
```

And I try to import it to MongoDB then how can I validate data on json file to make sure that correct data was imported.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: If that's your JSON file then it looks more like redirected output from a mongo shell rather than a proper json export. [`mongoexport`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/program/mongoexport/) produces valid JSON. ["Shell Mode"](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/mongodb-extended-json/#input-in-mongo-shell-mode) output can be used with `mongoimport` and some other supported methods, but things like `ISODate()` are not valid JSON and are simply not emitted from the proper tools.

Comment: In fact it you omit the trailing comma from the sample above ( which is probably only there because you truncated the data in your post ) , `mongoimport` will happily import the data as provided. But for general purposes the ["strict mode"](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/mongodb-extended-json/) default of `mongoexport` should be used instead.

Comment: @NeilLunn sorry, it is just a sample data. Please check my updated sample data. Is there any way to check `firstnumber` must be less than `secondnumber` if I use `mongoimport` to insert a new record. Or `mongoexport` only can valid json file.